# How to get specific data from firebase with Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

(EDİT)
I am getting error in below code, what I want to do is only get data of followed users, users are in a different collection, shared content is in a different collection, and
I'm getting an error on the 4th line, I hope I explained it correctly, I would appreciate if you could help.

Errors I get:

```
The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 
'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'data', correcting the name to 
the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 
'data'.
```

My Code:

```
 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').orderBy('datePublish',descending: true).snapshots().map((event) {
      List following = [];
      var userSnap = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots();
      if(Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser.following.contains(userSnap.data["uid"])){
        following.add(event);
        return following;
      }
      return following;

    }),
```

userSnap.data, data is not defined!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: The method 'snapshot' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'snapshot'.

Comment: The method 'includes' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'includes'.

Comment: The getter 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'data', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'data'.

Comment: I got these errors, what i am trying to do is get the data of followed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the errors you get. That also gives you a chance to format then to improve readability, and make it clear which exact line gives each error.

Comment: Many of them seem like syntax errors, so I recommend searching for those messages - and also keeping the reference documentation ready (for example, I think `snapshot()` may need to be `snapshots()`.